# Gazebo doesn't start even though no errors are reported

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is rather weird.
Gazebo refuses to start but no errors are reported...

The problem lies somewhere in the URDF file of the robot since commenting it out fixes things:

ROBOT URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from robot.xacro                    | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <!--This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.5.1-0-g916b5db  Build Version: 1.5.7152.31018
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.00390777224516517 -0.032446267219719 0.184169550820421"/>
      <mass value="4.20121630268732"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0149000386129946" ixy="-4.66831001352174E-09" ixz="5.23920338795194E-08" iyy="0.0234359493013497" iyz="0.000771538751024883" izz="0.0286744535302635"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.529411764705882 0.549019607843137 0.549019607843137 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="FL">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-5.55111512312578E-17 9.10729824887824E-18 -6.93889390390723E-18"/>
      <mass value="0.0615219544751675"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.54433425808419E-05" ixy="-1.45453466603006E-20" ixz="-1.00225538664655E-21" iyy="3.00921775305435E-05" iyz="2.309188417276E-21" izz="3.00921775305435E-05"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/FL.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/FL.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="FLJ" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" xyz="-0.162088045105054 0.0440194465480433 -0.0035605397876617"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="FL"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="FR">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="2.77555756156289E-17 -5.3776427755281E-17 3.46944695195361E-17"/>
      <mass value="0.0615219544751675"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.54433425808419E-05" ixy="-1.73616162087809E-20" ixz="-8.97406720914896E-21" iyy="3.00921775305435E-05" iyz="-2.24902265994014E-21" izz="3.00921775305435E-05"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/FR.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/FR.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="FRJ" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" xyz="0.169947769597777 0.0440194465480434 -0.00356053978766185"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="FR"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="BL">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-5.55111512312578E-17 7.85396053748499E-16 -1.38777878078145E-17"/>
      <mass value="0.0615219544751675"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.54433425808419E-05" ixy="-5.54431358512462E-21" ixz="2.27097066282367E-22" iyy="3.00921775305435E-05" iyz="2.73146067339844E-21" izz="3.00921775305435E-05"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/BL.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/BL.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="BLJ" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" xyz="-0.162088045105054 -0.0759805534519569 -0.00356053978766179"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="BL"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="BR">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-8.32667268468867E-17 7.03430369508595E-16 2.77555756156289E-17"/>
      <mass value="0.0615219544751675"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.54433425808419E-05" ixy="-7.26178700863739E-21" ixz="-6.24920580783796E-21" iyy="3.00921775305435E-05" iyz="-3.51228039755728E-21" izz="3.00921775305435E-05"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/BR.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/BR.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="BRJ" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.16991 -0.075981 -0.0035605"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="BR"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="TB">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-7.8063E-18 1.3878E-17 0.001"/>
      <mass value="0.36807"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00019523" ixy="7.0972E-20" ixz="-4.0656E-22" iyy="0.0026688" iyz="4.5169E-23" izz="0.0028638"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/TB.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.52941 0.54902 0.54902 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/TB.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="TBJ" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.003912 -0.086602 0.46844"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="TB"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <!--             LIDAR                     -->
  <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
    <sensor name="head_hokuyo_sensor" type="ray">
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>40</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.57079</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.57079</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.1</min>
          <max>30</max>
          <resolution>0.1</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so" name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller">
        <topicName>/scan</topicName>
        <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <joint name="TB_Lidar" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link="TB"/>
    <child link="hokuyo_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57079633" xyz="0 0 0.005"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
  <link name="hokuyo_link">
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
 

  <!--                Differential Drive                
     <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so" name="differential_drive_controller">
     <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
      <leftJoint>FLJ</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>FRJ</rightJoint>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
      <wheelSeperation>0.25</wheelSeperation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.07</wheelDiameter>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

    -->
  <!--                 Gazebo Transmission                        -->
  <transmission name="FLT">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="FLJ">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <mechanicalReduction>20</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="FRT">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="FRJ">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor2">
      <mechanicalReduction>20</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="BLT">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="BLJ">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor3">
      <mechanicalReduction>20</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <transmission name="BRT">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="BRJ">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor4">
      <mechanicalReduction>20</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  <!--                 Gazebo Ros Control Plugin              -->        
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so" name="gazebo_ros_control">
      <robotNamespace>/robot</robotNamespace>
      <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
      <legacyModeNS>true</legacyModeNS>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>


</robot>
```

OUTPUT FROM GAZEBO:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    tf_footprint_base (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [19490]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 6417d242-529f-11ea-a52c-5800e3916931
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [19503]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [19508]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [19517]
process[tf_footprint_base-4]: started with pid [19533]
process[spawn_model-5]: started with pid [19538]
[ INFO] [1582065513.017071930]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1582065513.017956573]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1582065513.042921100]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1582065513.043709858]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1582065513.417035, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from file
[INFO] [1582065513.417362, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1582065514.595613277, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[INFO] [1582065514.623878, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1582065514.633255624, 0.059000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[INFO] [1582065515.026068, 0.155000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1582065515.041137382, 0.155000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1582065515.041212855, 0.155000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)
[ INFO] [1582065515.043808316, 0.155000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1582065515.182815576, 0.155000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1582065515.182950455, 0.155000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /robot
[ INFO] [1582065515.183852027, 0.155000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[spawn_model-5] process has finished cleanly
```

But Gazebo has only a black screen...

RESULTS UNDER --verbose FLAG:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    tf_footprint_base (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6334]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 524b78ce-52af-11ea-a52c-5800e3916931
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6347]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [6353]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [6366]
process[tf_footprint_base-4]: started with pid [6379]
process[spawn_model-5]: started with pid [6380]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.16.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.16.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[ INFO] [1582072355.099776252]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[ INFO] [1582072355.101793823]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1582072355.161269042]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1582072355.161890009]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.12
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1582072355.478038, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from file
[INFO] [1582072355.478403, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1582072356.057583076, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[INFO] [1582072356.082674, 0.046000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1582072356.090963259, 0.054000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.12
[INFO] [1582072356.418210, 0.156000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1582072356.432143195, 0.156000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1582072356.432206848, 0.156000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)
[ INFO] [1582072356.433736436, 0.156000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1582072356.527392576, 0.156000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1582072356.527503462, 0.156000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /robot
[ INFO] [1582072356.528275304, 0.156000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[spawn_model-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/michael/.ros/log/524b78ce-52af-11ea-a52c-5800e3916931/spawn_model-5*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344513/gazebo-doesn%27t-start-even-though-no-errors-are-reported/) by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-02-18**:
What's labeled as `OUTPUT FROM GAZEBO` is actually output from `roslaunch` and the programs it launched. Gazebo classic prints nothing to console by default unless given the `--verbose` flag. Adding that flag may give more information about what went wrong.

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16560/how-to-use-roslaunch-having-gazebo-on-verbose-mode/

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-02-18**:
Run Gazebo under --verbose flag and added the results following my original question. Please check my question. I cannot see anything strange meaning no red marks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a pretty staright-forward log :

```
 gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
```

And at the beginning of the ouput of roslaunch :

```
PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True
```

So I assume that you don't define the parameter robot_description in your launch file and simply give it as an argument of the `spawn_model` node. In your launch file you simply need to add :

```
<!--  ******************** Robot Model ********************  -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find YOUR_PACKAGE)/urdf/URDF_NAME'"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-02-19**:
Great. That was the problem.
The thing I don't get is how did the Gazebo loaded the model at my previous attempts? Because the problem started at a specific point and on. Anyway thank you very much...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-02-19**:
If this has answered your question can you please mark the answer as correct ?

For your question I agree that it is rather strange that you could have loaded the model without the parameter `robot_description`, maybe if you show your launch file I could find something. Are you sure it was the correct model that was loaded into Gazebo when it worked ?

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-02-19**:
Yes 100%, because it was loading and after 2-3 re-loads it couldn't load.